# I can read from file but writing to file produces FileNotFoundException when using the same path

Tags: java, file

I've setup a class which handles config files like this:

```
public class ConfigHandler{

    private static ConfigHandler singleton;

    //filepath working...
    private String filePath = "./com.triemond.communicate.config/config.cfg";

    private Properties configFile;

    public ConfigHandler(Communicator communicator){
        configFile = new Properties();
        InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
        try {
            configFile.load(stream);
            stream.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void save() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, URISyntaxException{
        URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource(filePath);
        File file = new File(resourceUrl.toURI());
        OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        configFile.store(stream, null);
        stream.close();
    }

    public String getProperty(String key){
        return this.configFile.getProperty(key);

    }

    public void setProperty(String key, String value) {
        configFile.setProperty(key, value);
    }
```

I am able to construct this class just fine (which means that the properties can be read from the file.) However I cannot, using the same path, write to that file. I get a FileNotFoundException.

Whenever I change the path of the file I get this:

```
- [Load]  An error occured while loading the config file
```

as an error, which means that the catch caught some exception of which this is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.triemond.communicate.handlers.ConfigHandler.save(ConfigHandler.java:36)
at com.triemond.communicate.handlers.Communicator.saveProperties(Communicator.java:292)
at com.triemond.communicate.handlers.Communicator.quit(Communicator.java:155)
at com.triemond.communicate.listeners.MenuListener.close(MenuListener.java:129)
at com.triemond.communicate.listeners.MenuListener.actionPerformed(MenuListener.java:42)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Why can I read from a file but not write to it?

Comment: *which means that the catch caught some exception* So emit the details of the exception. It should be obvious that `communicator.writeToField("- [Load]  An error occured while loading the config file");
        }` is insufficient.  "An error"?  How about logging the *details* of the error?

Comment: That's not the problem though... when reading a file everything goes fine and no exception is thrown with the `filePath` setup as shown above. however I cannot write using this file path... If I change the `filePath` variable I do get the exception.

Comment: @BRHSM I think Andrews means that you error message is useless since it doesn't give any detail about the error you get. You should at least do a `e.printStackTrace();` or better(?) give it to the Communicator

Comment: ahh, I'm doing that but I just kept it out on here to make the example shorter... the `communicator.writeToField()` method is used to send error messages to the user, which should not be a stackTrace

Comment: a NullPointerException at `configFile.load(stream);` which is due to stream being `null` which happens when the file is not found. But this does not happen when I use the path as written above... It's only when I invoke `save()` that I get an exception. Again a NullPointerException...

Comment: @BRHSM sorry I have missed your last comment. 
>  this does not happen when I use the path as written above.
So with which path? Where is the file supposed to be?

Comment: I've made a folder `com.triemond.communicate.config` inside the src folder of my project in which I've put the `config.cfg` file. The path `./com.triemond.communicate.config/config.cfg` does not cause an exception while other filepaths I've tried do result in that exception.

Comment: The exception thrown in the code has nothing to do with the problem! The problem is that when I use the path WHICH DOES NOT CAUSE AN EXCEPTION I can read a file but I cannot write to it... It has nothing to do with that exception as the exception is not thrown

Comment: But it does actually have everything to do with the code specially for File IO errors. It is important even though File IO Exceptions typically are vague; they do help.

Comment: How is an exception which is not thrown essential for this problem? (not sarcastic)

Comment: @BRHSM So it maybe because your file is locked or read-only. Giving exception details might have helped. The info is generally given in the complete message.

Comment: here you go, I edited the question

Comment: @BRHSM We are actually interested in the `FileNotFoundException` you complain about. The NPE is totally uninteresting.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce this exception from the saving of the file. I can't however reproduce the `FileNotFoundException` I got before

Comment: @BRHSM Well, what can we do then? (Voting to close as not reproducible.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you load a resource from the classpath:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
```

But attempt to write to the file based on URL of that resource:

```
URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource(filePath);
File file = new File(resourceUrl.toURI());
```

Loading probably works because you probably has the corresponding resource on your classpath. It might be very well a resource packaged in some JAR. But it is not a file in the filesystem.

The URL you get from `getClass().getResource(filePath)` might very well end up being something like `jar:file:/.../some.jar!/com.triemond.communicate.config/config.cfg`. You attempt to write to it as a file - this might very well produce `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: this might very well be a problem, How could I go about fixing this though?

Comment: @BRHSM You have to move the config file out of your JARs and use it as a file. You can't really update a resource inside a JAR.